# Vectorspace of polynomials / smallest subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vectorspace of all polynomials with degree (leq 4), and let
$p(x) = x + x^2$ and $q(x) = x-x^3$ define the smallest subspace of $V$ which contains $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.

since we have polynomials up to degree 4, the dimension of the vector space = 5 ?
thus the coefficents for $p(x)$ would be
$a_0 = 0, a_1 =1, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 0, a_4 = 0$

for $q(x)$ would be
$b_0 = 0, b_1 =1, b_2 = 0, b_3 = -1, b_4 = 0$
so when writing them as a vector
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 1\\1 & 0\\0 & -1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
so these vectors are clearly linearl independent, but how to proceed from here? how can I get the smallest subspace?

Comment: Typo: $b_3 = -1$

Comment: You just take the span of those two vectors and by definition it is the smallest subspace containing them

Comment: @StevenCreech, thank you, since the vectors are independent, the span would be just the  two vectors themselves?

Comment: All linear combinations of those two vectors

Comment: @StevenCreech: Of course, I meant that I write only these two vectors in the span and do not need to extend to a full basis of P4?